# Cant do subtractions with negative numbers

Tags: python, calculator

```py
print('=====CALCULADORA==========')
conta = str(input('')).strip()
operadores = ('+', '-', 'x', '/')
for o in range(0,4):
    if operadores[o] in conta[1:len(conta)]:
        if operadores[o] == '+':
            print(f'{conta[0:conta.find("+")].strip()} + {conta[conta.find("+") + 1:].strip()} = {int(conta[0:conta.find("+")]) + int(conta[conta.find("+") + 1:])}')
        if operadores[o] == '-':
            print(f'{conta[0:conta.find("-")].strip()} - {conta[conta.find("-") + 1:].strip()} = {int(conta[0:conta.find("-")]) - int(conta[conta.find("-") + 1:])}')
```

Im creating a simple calculator code.

Doing additions works, but when I try to do operations like -4-6, the program dont work. An error appears, saying: " ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' "

The code was supposed to do the expressions correctly, it parcially works, it seems the problem is when I repeat the operators. -4 + 3, or +4 - 3 actually works, but +4 + 3, or -4-3, dont.

Comment: Are you familiar with the classic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm? Writing a calculator is harder than it might appear initially...

Answer (score 1):

Take a close look at what your code does when you enter `'-4-6'`.

First the data entry:

```
conta = str(input('')).strip()
```

That works as expected, although this would do the exact same:

```
conta = input().strip()
```

Then a defintion of operators, and your looping over it:

```
operadores = ('+', '-', 'x', '/')
for o in range(0,4):
    ...  # code using operadores[o]
```

This also works, although again it's more complicated than it needs to be:

```
operadores = '+-x/'
for o in operadores:
    ...  # code using o as the current operator
```

Then the problematic part:

```
    if operadores[o] in conta[1:len(conta)]:
```

You specifically skip the first character, probably to avoid detecting the `-` at the start as the actual operator. However, the `-` is still there in `'-4-6'`.

Then, later:

```
        if operadores[o] == '-':
            print(f'{conta[0:conta.find("-")].strip()} - {conta[conta.find("-") + 1:].strip()} = {int(conta[0:conta.find("-")]) - int(conta[conta.find("-") + 1:])}')
```

Here, you use `conta.find("-")` to find the position of the operator, but of course here it actually finds the first `-`, not the second.

You could fix this code like this:

```
print('=====CALCULADORA==========')
conta = str(input('')).strip()
operadores = '+-x/'
for o in operadores:
    if o in conta[1:len(conta)]:
        if o == '+':
            print(f'{conta[0:conta[1:].find("+")+1].strip()} + {conta[conta[1:].find("+")+2:].strip()} = {int(conta[0:conta[1:].find("+")+1].strip()) + int(conta[conta[1:].find("+")+2:].strip())}')
        if o == '-':
            print(f'{conta[0:conta[1:].find("-")+1].strip()} - {conta[conta[1:].find("-")+2:].strip()} = {int(conta[0:conta[1:].find("-")+1].strip()) - int(conta[conta[1:].find("-")+2:].strip())}')
```

However, that's still wildly complicated with a lot of reptition. It also doesn't consider something like `'4--2'`, which is subtracting `-2` from `4`, and `6` should be the result. Never mind longer expressions, like `'4+3+2'`.

It makes more sense to break up an input string into tokens and then perform the operations as they should be. So, `'-4+3+2'` would be broken up in `['-4', '+', '3', '+', '2']` and you can compute the result going over that.

Of course this problem has been solved many times before, so there's good examples out there of even better strategies.